# creating a calculated column using SQL COUNT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Lets say I work for a call center and I closed 10 calls but opened 20 calls in the day. The "real" figure is actually `-10`. Even though a target is 10 calls to close, The worker failed because 20 calls were opened.

I would like to write an SQL report to reflect this. But my problem seems to be I cannot calculate figures from aggregate counts.

```
SELECT workername                       AS Name, 
       (SELECT Count(closeddate) 
        FROM   mybanksupport 
        WHERE  closeddate = NULL)       OPENCALLS, 
       (SELECT Count(closeddate) 
        FROM   mybanksupport 
        WHERE  closeddate = NOT NULL)   CLOSEDCALLS, 
       (SELECT opencalls - closedcalls) REALCALLS 
FROM   mybanksupport
```

In short, I want to calculate 2 column count values and then use that value to produce another calculated column called Real Calls

Comment: BTW, answered below which I think fixes your question, but pointing out that I'm thinking you also need some more qualification? Sone your selects from mybanksupport don't you need to qualify by workername? Like you want the count of closeddate only for that specific worker. As you have it, I think would do count for ALL workers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`COUNT` only counts values, i.e., it ignores `NULL`s. This property can be used to simply your expression:

```
SELECT workername, closedCalls, totalCalls - closedCalss AS openCalls
FROM   (SELECT   workername, COUNT(closeddate) AS closedcalls, COUNT(*) totalCalls
        FROM     mybanksupport
        GROUP BY workername) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Write as subquery then you can use the fields form that as you want

```
Select
  workername
, OPENCALLS
, CLOSEDCALLS
, (OPENCALLS - CLOSEDCALLS)  REALCALLS
From
(
SELECT workername                       AS Name, 
       (SELECT Count(closeddate) 
        FROM   mybanksupport 
        WHERE  closeddate = NULL)       OPENCALLS, 
       (SELECT Count(closeddate) 
        FROM   mybanksupport 
        WHERE  closeddate = NOT NULL)   CLOSEDCALLS, 
FROM   mybanksupport 
) T1
```

Comment: Thanks, @DanBracuk. I was following his original query, but commented that same on the original post.